# Inserting an image into RadRichTextBox (Telerik) from clipboard or by drag-and-drop

Tags: wpf, telerik, richtextbox

Is it possible to insert an image into Telerik RadRichTextBox from a clipboard or by draging and drop?

I tried to paste an image copied to the clipboard. As wee see at the photo below, something with the white background is insterted. But it isn't an expected photo.

[image]

```html
<telerik:RadRichTextBox x:Name="RADRichTextBox" MaxWidth="250" BorderBrush="Black" IsSelectionMiniToolBarEnabled="True" DocumentInheritsDefaultStyleSettings="True" FontSize="14" ForceCursor="True" IsSpellCheckingEnabled="True" Height="50" MaxHeight="100">
      <telerik:RadDocument x:Name="RADDocument" DefaultPageLayoutSettings="600,800" />
</telerik:RadRichTextBox>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add an event :

```html
CommandExecuting="RADRichTextBox_CommandExecuting"
```

2. Paste this code inside the créated event :

```html
if (e.Command is PasteCommand)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;        
        if (System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.ContainsImage())
           {
               MemoryStream lStream = new MemoryStream();
               System.Drawing.Image lImage = null;
                
               lImage = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetImage();
                
               lImage.Save(lStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
               lStream.Position = 0;
                
               this.RADRichTextBox.InsertImage(lStream, "Png");
            }
                
         else if (System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.ContainsText())
            {               
                    this.RADRichTextBox.Insert(System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText());
            }
     }
```